# WordPress in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I've just checked through my logs and I see a massive error related to

**in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given** in /var/www/live/wp-content/plugins/tours/templates/single-custom-post/tour-style.php on line 55

Here the code in question:

```
    $my_articles = array();
    foreach($articles as $article) {
        $article_tour_styles = get_post_meta($article->ID, 'show_on_tour_styles', true);
        if(in_array($postid, $article_tour_styles)) {
            $my_articles[] = $article;
        }
    }
```

What would I need to change here in order to have this fix and sorted? Some expert help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: the [in_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function expects the second parameter to be an _array_. Instead, it's receiving a _string_ from that code snippet. If you're the developer of this plugin you need to add some extra validations to prevent this issue from happening. If it's not your plugin, you'll want to reach out to its developer and ask them to fix that for you. If that's not an option and you're the one who should fix this issue, reading the PHP documentation is a good place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do `if($article_tour_styles)` before `if(in_array($postid, $article_tour_styles))`.

Also, use `json_encode` before adding the `'show_on_tour_styles'` post meta.
When you retrieve it use `json_decode`.

Answer (score 0):

It would be false in get_post_meta as setting it true returns single value and on false it returns an array.
$article_tour_styles = get_post_meta($article->ID, 'show_on_tour_styles', false);